# Search Dict using List and make new Dict

Tags: python

struggling to figure this out.  I have a dictionary like this:

```
pprint(mydict)
{'bob': {'address': '1 bob place, bobtown', 'fullname': 'Boby McBoberton'},
 'fred': {'address': '1 fred place, fredtown', 'fullname': 'Freddy Frederton'},
 'john': {'address': '1 john place, johntown', 'fullname': 'John McJonerton'}}
```

Then, i have a list of usernames, like this:

```
print(admins)
['bob', 'fred']
```

What i need to do is use the names from `admins` and search through `mydict` and create a new dict with just the name and address.

so the end result should be something like:

```
{'bob': {'address': '1 bob place, bobtown'},
 'fred': {'address': '1 fred place}},
```

any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension like this

```
>>> d = {'bob': {'fullname': 'Boby McBoberton', 'address': '1 bob place, bobtown'}, 'john': {'fullname': 'John McJonerton', 'address': '1 john place, johntown'}, 'fred': {'fullname': 'Freddy Frederton', 'address': '1 fred place, fredtown'}}
>>> admins = ['bob', 'fred']
>>> 
>>> {k:dict(address = d[k]['address']) for k in admins}
{'bob': {'address': '1 bob place, bobtown'}, 'fred': {'address': '1 fred place, fredtown'}}
```

Comment: hmm this gives me a "keyword can't be an expression" error when running against my code

Comment: ah nevermind that comment, i just fat fingered it.  Thanks, this works!  What would be the most "pythonic" way to approach this... since there seems to be multiple options here.

Comment: @Dave0 This would be the most pythonic way. In addition, list comprehensions and dict comprehensions are faster than your normal for loop. My answer below worked, but it's not as pythonic as this one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
next_dict = {key, mydict[key]['address'] for key in (mydict.keys() & set(admins))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
out_dict = {}

for admin in admins:
    if admin in mydict.keys():
        out_dict[admin] = {'address': mydict[admin]['address']}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop through `admins` list
2. If admin found in original_dict, add it to the final_dict

This way, if an admin is not present in original_dict, code will not break.
Code as below:

```
original_dict= {'bob': {'address': '1 bob place, bobtown', 'fullname': 'Boby McBoberton'},
                 'fred': {'address': '1 fred place, fredtown', 'fullname': 'Freddy Frederton'},
                 'john': {'address': '1 john place, johntown', 'fullname': 'John McJonerton'}}
admins = ['bob','fred','pavan']
final_dict = {}
for admin in admins:
    if admin in original_dict:
        final_dict[admin] = {original_dict[admin]['address']}
print (final_dict)
```